# Unsupported data type for column geoloc

Tags: mapinfo, oracle-spatial

I can open the layer on QGis but in MapInfo I got that error.

I already have other layers I can open without any problem, is just with one I get this error.

[image]

Comment: Did you make this table mappable?

Comment: @CL. Not sure about that. I know my map guys already have work on this layer before, so don't understand why now is broken.. How can I make it mappable ?

Comment: Table / Maintenance / Make DBMS Table Mappable